# How to construct a given group as multiplicative group of field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

Question:

**Assume an abelian group $G$ is given. Then, is there a field $F$ such that $F^{\times} \cong G$ 
? What is the necessary and sufficient condition about G?**

I already know :

1. If $G$ is finite and $\# G + 1$ is not power of any prime, then such a F can not exist.
2. The multiplicative group of finite field is cyclic. So, if finite group $G$ is not cyclic, $F$ can not exist.

Comment: Hint: The finite group of a field is cyclic

Comment: @Minz I think you meant to say that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: This is easy when $G$ is a finite group, but much more difficult when $G$ is infinite.

Comment: See this question on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13017/which-commutative-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-field